# Biber fails on minimal example with arara

Tags: biblatex, xetex, biber

Here's my minimal example:

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: biber
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=nty]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\begin{document}
Citation\cite{Walco2008}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

`mwe.bib` file contains the following:

```
% This file was created with JabRef 2.10.
% Encoding: UTF8

@Book{Walco2008,
  Title                    = {Pain in Children},
  Author                   = {Gary A. Walco and Kenneth R. Goldschneider},
  Publisher                = {Humana Press},
  Year                     = {2008},

  __markedentry            = {[ilija.pavlic:6]},
  Owner                    = {ilija.pavlic},
  Timestamp                = {2014.06.09},
  Url                      = {http://www.amazon.com/Pain-Children-Gary-A-Walco-ebook/dp/B008BB7LUW%3FSubscriptionId%3D0JYN1NVW651KCA56C102%26tag%3Dtechkie-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB008BB7LUW}
}
```

When I try to compile that, I get the following failure message from biber:

```
Running Biber... 

Use of uninitialized value $llabel in concatenation (.) or string at Biber.pm line 664.
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at Biber/SortLists.pm line 77.
INFO - This is Biber 1.5
INFO - Logfile is 'mwe.blg'
INFO - Reading 'mwe.bcf'
WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.6, expected version 2.3
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'mwe.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'mwe.bib'
FAILURE
```

What do I need to fix to get this minimal example cite and print the bibliography?

Comment: Works fine here, though I have Biber 1.8, while you have 1.5.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. After the update it started working for me as well. Thank you! Could you convert your comment to answer?

Comment: I'd rather close as 'off-topic' if that's ok with you.

Comment: I have no problems with that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem caused by an old version of Biber, solved by updating.

Comment: This is not off-topic, and i would appreciate to see the answer (update your biber) as an actual answer. Then i would not have to read all the comments...